# Add autocomplete search to nopcomerce

Tags: c#, razor, nopcommerce

I'm new to nopcommerce and I'm trying to add autocomplete searchbox on configuration page in nopcommerce. I know that there is a search box model in standart configurayion, but how I can implement it?

Edit: This is my code where I'm Trying to add searchbox

```
@model Nop.Plugin.Widgets.NivoSlider.Models.ConfigurationModel
@using Nop.Web.Framework;
@using Nop.Web.Models.Catalog;
@Html.Action("StoreScopeConfiguration", "Setting", new { area = "Admin"})
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    <fieldset>
        <legend><strong>@T("Plugins.Widgets.NivoSlider.Picture1")</strong></legend>
        <table class="adminContent">
            <tr>
                <td class="adminTitle">
                    @Html.OverrideStoreCheckboxFor(model => model.Picture1Id_OverrideForStore, model => model.Picture1Id, Model.ActiveStoreScopeConfiguration)
                    @Html.NopLabelFor(model => model.Picture1Id):
                </td>
                <td class="adminData">
                    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Picture1Id)
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Picture1Id)
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td class="adminTitle">
                    @Html.OverrideStoreCheckboxFor(model => model.Text1_OverrideForStore, model => model.Text1, Model.ActiveStoreScopeConfiguration)
                    <div class="search-box">
                        @Html.Action("SearchBox", "Catalog")
                    </div>
                    @Html.NopLabelFor(model => model.Text1):
                </td>
                <td class="adminData">
                    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Text1)
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Text1)
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
```

Answer (score 2):

Hi You can add autocomplete same as search box in the front site. It has also auto complete. Just implement autocomplete as standard [jquery](https://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/) does. It needs source data that data you will bring from database based on the typed word in textbox.